# SQL statement to Insert records from table A and table B into table C with a condition

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Values inserted from table B should be from one field in table B if another field in table B matches my defined value.

Example:
I have a variable-- int new = 6,

- Table A has fields: first, second, third, fourth, sixth
- Table B has fields: seventh, eighth, ninth
- Table C has fields: first, second, third, fourth, eighth, ninth

Insert into table C values (first, second, third, fourth) from table A and values eighth and ninth from table B if eighth matches a defined value stored in a variable say variable new.

I have done my programming in C#.

Code: The code below only works for exporting all records from decimals table into numbers table. I have tried several different tweaks into this code ie. even adding another select statement but haven't succeeded.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tablec (first, second, third, fourth, fifth) 
            SELECT first, second, third, fourth FROM tablea";
```

A simple example would help alot.

Comment: I wonder why you have to insert the data into a new table?  That's duplication - always a bad idea for code of any kind.  Without knowing more, I'd say that key relationships or views would be preferred to copying values.

Comment: How can we know which data to take from a and which from b? anyways you are looking for a simple join

Comment: @sagi, how would that look in an sql statement with the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a join, such as:

```
INSERT INTO tablec (first, second, third, fourth, fifth, eighth, ninth) 
    SELECT a.first, a.second, a.third, a.fourth, b.eighth, b.ninth
    FROM tablea a CROSS JOIN
         tableb b
    WHERE b.eighth = $new;
```

Comment: i understand the question is to insert into a third table, but given the duplication of data that already exists, would it not be better to explain why  its not good practice?

Comment: @Takarii . . . There are many reasons why an application would want to create a temporary table, and the question provides no guidance on what the OP is doing.  For all I know, the OP wants to create a table with data, validate it, and then export it to someone for analysis.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like

```
SELECT A.first, A.second, A.third, A.forth, B.eighth, B.ninth 
FROM A  
INNER JOIN A on A.id = B.id
WHERE B.eighth = yourvalue
```

This is assuming you have your keys set up. There is no need to move data to a third table, as mentioned in the comments it would be duplication which isn't ideal.